# PHP: get only one file from a directory of 10000 files based on filename containing unix stamp

Tags: php

I'm trying to scan directory and getting only the latest file added in the directory using filename sorting

my files have different file names but all are preceded w/ the unix_timestamp eg:
    1423285600_smas293.jpg
    1423285700_smas11.doc

So I know of a method to do this 
    $files = scandir($dir, SCANDIR_SORT_DESCENDING);
    $newest_file = $files[0];

but that seems to load all the files into an array first.. and if i have 100K (theoretically) files? what then? Will the server become sluggish?

So i was hoping to scan and retrieve just a limited number of files into array, if that's possible --- or any other strategies that basically gets what I need done..

Regards

Comment: Have a look at `glob()`. It gives you the ability to define the string of the file you seek. http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you could use `opendir()` and `readdir()` the directory entries one by one, and just remember the alphabetically biggest filename. It's what `scandir()` and `glob()` ultimately do under water. That way you don't have to load everything in memory; though you'll still have to iterate over all your theoretically 100K files:

```
<?php    
$biggest = false;    
if ($fp = opendir('/tmp')) {
    while ( ($entry = readdir($fp)) )
    if (! $biggest or ($entry > $biggest) )
        $biggest = $entry;
    closedir($fp);
}
print("Biggest: " . $biggest . "\n");    
?>
```

Ultimately it would of course be a better solution to store your files in folders by days or weeks. Your filesystem will ultimately choke when you create that many files in just one directory.

Comment: i was afraid there was no easy solution to this. but thanks for confirming.

by the way, what is the default sorting order of readdir()? I mean when it scans through the dir, how does it decide w/c file to start with? or is this random? I'm assuming this must be alphabetical or by datetime of the file...

Comment: There is unfortunately no default sorting in the list of files. All happens afterwords. The order of spitting out the names of files is totally up to the filesystem implementation; usually it'll just appear random to your program.